# Find the asymptote of $y=\frac{x^2+x+7}{\sqrt{2x+1}}$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

> Find the asymptote of $y=\frac{x^2+x+7}{\sqrt{2x+1}}$

I found one of the asymptotes which is $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ but couldn't find the other. I tried using L'Hopital's rule but it turns out the answer I got was wrong after I plotted the graphs. And then I'm stuck. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you guys.

Comment: The only other asymptote is possible as $x \to \infty$ in which case the numerator looks like $x^2$ and the denominator is $\sqrt{2x}$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we factor out $\frac1{\sqrt2}$ from the denominator and complete the square in the numerator, we get
$$y=\frac1{\sqrt2}\cdot\frac{(x+1/2)^2+27/4}{\sqrt{x+1/2}}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left((x+1/2)^{3/2}+\frac{27/4}{\sqrt{x+1/2}}\right)$$
The other asymptote may be found by dropping the last term:
$$y\sim\frac1{\sqrt2}(x+1/2)^{3/2}$$
This is a curvilinear asymptote.

Comment: Isn't an asymptote a line by definition?

Comment: @peter.petrov No. Asymptotes can be anything that is simpler and approximates the original function.

Comment: Yeah but... in college math they define it as a line. What you're talking about is curvilinear asymptote, I guess. I doubt the question was asked in that sense. I don't know with certainty though...

Comment: @peter.petrov The question never said "linear asymptote".

Comment: Yeah, that is true :)

Answer (score 1):

If by **asymptote** you mean a **line**, then there's no other asymptote.

Why? Because

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2+x+7}{\sqrt{2x+1}}$$

which can be rewritten as:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot (2x+1)\sqrt{2x+1} + \frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{27}{\sqrt{2x+1}}$$

So there does not exist a line

$$g(x) = ax + b$$ such that:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} |f(x)-g(x)| = 0$$

Why?

Because this term $(2x+1)\sqrt{2x+1}$ grows faster than any linear function as $x$ goes to infinity.